# Android studio with andengine physicsbox2d extension

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, andengine-gles-2

I'm trying to include andengine physicsbox2d-extension in my project.
It was very easy using eclipse (Just import the project and include in path)

But now I'm trying to do it in android studio

I tried those 2 method and get exception in both of them

Method 1: Include andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar

this cause the following run time exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.myproject.myproject-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.myproject.myproject-2]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
        at org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
```

Method 2 : Include andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension project

this cause a compilation error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files\Android\android-ndk-r10\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\MYUSER\AndroidstudioProjects\myproject\andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension\build\intermediates\ndk\release\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:\Users\MYUSER\AndroidstudioProjects\myproject\andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\MYUSER\AndroidstudioProjects\myproject\andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension\build\intermediates\ndk\release\lib APP_ABI=all
Error Code:
    1
```

Does anyone manage to import this extension to android studio?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can go on with Method 1:

- include `andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar`
- create a folder named `jniLibs` inside your app project directory and copy `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` [folders](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/tree/GLES2/libs) to it

Answer (score 0):

your project is ignoring .so files from the extension project.

you can follow my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068202/2026280

or

Its very simple. Follow this simple steps

**1)** Create a new folder called **"lib"** inside the libs folder of the **main app**.

**2)** Copy all the folders ie.armabi , armabi-v7a etc from **andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/libs** folder, and paste in in the previously created **"lib"** folder in **main app**.

**3)** Now compress the **"lib"** folder as **"lib.zip"** and rename it to **"lib.jar"**.
this changes the **zip** extension to **jar**.

**4)** Finally add a line -- **compile files('lib.jar')** under dependencies{} in **Build.gradle** file of your **main app**.

**5)** Clean and build the project.